# How to save bar code scanned image when read code

Tags: flutter, dart

I used [qrscan](https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan#-example-tab-) plugin for bar code scanning. I want to capture & save image of barcode simultaneously read the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan QR Code from your lib [qrscan](https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan#-example-tab-)
2. Read QR code from image as String
3. add New Lib QR code genrator from String [qr](https://pub.dev/packages/qr)
4. save genrated image in your local storage

Comment: Then you have to deep dive in qrscan plugin

Comment: Do I need JAVA , because this plugin is developed in java